# If $\tau$ is strictly finer than the standard topology $\tau_{st}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, prove their difference $\tau \setminus \tau_{st}$ is uncountable

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I think I have a proof, but it's a little convoluted.

Since $\tau$ is strictly finer than than $\tau_{st}$, there is an open set $U \in \tau$ such that $U \notin \tau_{st}$. For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the sets $U \cup (-\infty, x+1) $ and $U \cup (x, +\infty)$ are both open in $\tau$. However, at most one of the two can be in $\tau_{st}$. For the sake of contradiction, assume both are in $\tau_{st}$, then so is their union, which is $U$, which cannot be true. Thus for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have constructed at least one set open in $\tau$ which is not in $\tau_{st}$, proving their difference is not countable.

Is this correct? Can it be done easier?

Comment: The argument is incomplete. You have to consider the possibility that $U \cup (x,\infty) =U \cup (y,\infty)$ may hold for lots of pairs $x,y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the sets you are considering look at $U\setminus \{x\}$ for $x \in \mathbb R$.  You can see that $U\setminus \{x\}\neq U\setminus \{y\}$ whenever $x,y \in U$ and  $x \neq y$ ; also $U\setminus \{x\} \in \tau_{st} $ for at most one  $x$  (because $U =U\setminus \{x\})\cup U\setminus \{y\}))$ for $x \neq y$ and $U\setminus \{x\} \in \tau $ for all $x$.  When $U$ is countable consideration of the intervals $U \cup (x,x+1)$ can be used. I leave the details to you.

Comment: Won't $U \cup \{x\}^c$ equal $U \cup \{y\}^c$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are either both in $U$ or both not in $U$?

Comment: @kmm You are right. I have corrected the proof.

Comment: I am sorry if I am missing something obvious, but if $x \in U^c$, won't $U \cup \{x\}^c$ just be $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\}$, which is in $\tau_{st}$, so it's not in $\tau \setminus \tau_{st}$

Comment: @kmm Please check if the proof is OK now.

Comment: It looks good to me, thank you very much.

Comment: It does hinge on $U$ itself being uncountable, I'm not sure if that is obvious.

Comment: @kmm See my answer now.